# Variable in JS + API consuming: Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm new both to React and Javascript, and I'm trying to build a page consuming REST API. It works fine with the exception of the data I want to extract from the API and it doesn't seem to be working.
In the data variable is the copy from my API endpoint. The `const teacherMapped` and `lessonsMapped` are working fine, but the `const teachers` which is pretty much the same, fails with

```
 Line 97:37 'teachers' is not defined no-undef
```

As you can see from the commented code, I tried declaring the variable in different places unsuccessfully. 
Could you please give me some hints of how to make it right?
Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card'
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions'
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent'
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import AppbarMui from './components/AppbarMui'
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie'

const data = 
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Potion-Making - Beginner's course",
    "description": "This highly-rated online course will guide you step-by-step through the composition of your first potion and other related aspects of potion-making",
    "lessons": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Induction - What is a potion making?",
            "description": "What is a potion making and what will you need during our course?",
            "course": "Potion-Making - Beginner's course"
        }
    ],
    "teacher": [
        {
            "teacher_name": "John Doe"
        }
    ]
}

const teacherMapped = data.teacher.map(tea => (tea.teacher_name))

const lessonsMapped = data.lessons.map(less => (less.description))

class CourseView extends Component { 

    state = {
        oneCourse: []

    };

    componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}${window.location.pathname}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ oneCourse: data })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log)

const teachers = this.state.oneCourse.teacher.map(tea => { return `${tea.teacher_name}`})

}


enroll = event => {
    let cookieValue = (document.cookie.match(/^(?:.*;)?\s*apitoken\s*=\s*([^;]+)(?:.*)?$/)||[,null])[1]
    if (cookieValue.length > 0) {
            fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}${window.location.pathname}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                            'Authorization': `Token ${cookieValue}`},
                body: JSON.stringify(this.props.cookie)
                }).then( resp => resp.json())
                .then( res => {
                    alert (res)
                })
                .catch( error => console.log(error))}
    else {
        alert ('An Error occurred!')
    }}

  //teachersMapped =()=> {if (!this.state.oneCourse.teacher){ this.state.oneCourse.teacher.map(tea => (tea.teacher_name))}};

//const teachers = this.state.oneCourse.teacher.map(tea => { return `${tea.teacher_name}`})

  render () {
    return(
        <div>
          <AppbarMui />
                <Card>

                    <CardMedia style={{height: 300}}
                    component="img"
                        image="../img/room.jpg"
                        />
                    <CardContent>

                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="headline" component="h2" color="secondary">
                            {this.state.oneCourse.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography component="p">
                            {this.state.oneCourse.description}
                        </Typography>
                        <h4>Teacher</h4>
                        <Typography>
                        Teacher is {teachers || "To be determined"}
                        </Typography>
                        <h4>Lessons</h4>
                         <Typography>
                        {lessonsMapped || "To be continued"}
                        </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small" color="secondary" target="_blank" onClick={this.enroll}>
                            Enroll on Course
                        </Button> 

                    </CardActions>
                </Card>

        </div>
   ) 
}


}
export default withCookies (CourseView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define teachers as a property of the class, so try `this.teachers` to access it in methods on the class.

Comment: Thank you, that worked (really stupid of me to have forgotten it). However, now I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, though the teacher is definitely there in the API. This line: `teachersMapped =()=> {if (this.state.oneCourse.teacher){ this.state.oneCourse.teacher.map(tea => (tea.teacher_name))}};` doesn't throw the error, but not giving me the teacher... Do you know where the problem may lie?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like your oneCourse array is not being properly filled with the data you expect. Try a console.log in the fetch to see what sort of data you're getting back from your api and make sure it's formatted the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue. You define the teachers variable inside of the CourseView componentDidMount function. Therefore this variable will not exist within the scope of the render method. You must either make the variable a global variable or state of the component depending on your use case.

Comment: thank you. I tried defining it differently, but even with the variable declared in the componentDidMount method, calling the variable through `this.teachers` works. Now I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` though... Do you know what's causing it?

Comment: The error is from trying to read an undefined value this.teachers. this.teachers will always return null or undefined because it is trying to access an undeclared property of this. What you should do is define teachers in the CourseView state. Once the teachers variable is binded to this, we can update that value inside of the componentDidMount function. Then the updated value will be available inside of your render method.